# Question about least fixed point of a monotone continuous function.

Tags: functions

I have been reading a book on set theory and have come to an exercise that I am having some trouble with. The question is :

> Prove that if $\overline{X}$ is the least fixed point of a monotone continuous function
> $F : \mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$, then
> $\overline{X} = \bigcup_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}} X_{i}$ where we define recursively
> $X_{0} = \emptyset$, $X_{i+1} = F(X_{i})$.

If $F$ is monotone it means :
\begin{equation}
X \subseteq Y \subseteq A \Rightarrow F(X) \subseteq F(Y)
\end{equation}
If $X$ is a fixed point of $F$ then $F(X) = X$.

If $F$ is continuous then :
\begin{equation}
F\left( \bigcup_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}} X_{i} \right) = \bigcup_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}} F(X_{i})
\end{equation}
holds for any non-decreasing sequence of subsets of $A$. So
$\langle X_{i} \; \mid \; i \in \boldsymbol{N} \rangle$ is nondecreasing if
$X_{i} \subseteq X_{j}$ holds whenever $i \leq j$.

Here $\boldsymbol{N}$ denotes the natural numbers (same notation as book here).

My partial attempt at a solution is below :

First show that $\{ X_{i} \}_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}}$ is non-decreasing. Can use inductive argument.

We see :
\begin{align}
n = 0  & \Rightarrow X_{n} \subseteq X_{n+1} \\
 & \Rightarrow X_{0} \subseteq X_{1} \\
 & \Rightarrow \emptyset \subseteq F(\emptyset) \; \checkmark
\end{align}
We know this because $\emptyset \subseteq B$ for any set $B$.

Now prove :
\begin{equation}
X_{n} \subseteq X_{n+1} \Rightarrow X_{n+1} \subseteq X_{n+2}
\end{equation}
We see due to monotonicity :
\begin{align}
X_{n} \subseteq X_{n+1}  
 & \Rightarrow F(X_{n}) \subseteq F(X_{n+1}) = X_{n+2} \\
 & \Rightarrow X_{n+1} \subseteq F(X_{n+1}) = X_{n+2}\\
 & \Rightarrow X_{n+1} \subseteq X_{n+2} \; \checkmark
\end{align}
So :
\begin{equation}
X_{n} \subseteq X_{n+1} \; \forall n \in \boldsymbol{N}
\end{equation}
and $\{X_{i}\}_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}}$ is non-decreasing. $\checkmark$

Let's say $X_{n} \in \{ X_{i} \}_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}}$ is a fixed point of $F$. Then :
\begin{align}
F(X_{n}) = X_{n} 
 & \Rightarrow X_{n+1} = F(X_{n}) = X_{n} \\
 & \Rightarrow X_{n+1} = X_{n} \\
 & \Rightarrow X_{i} = X_{n} \; \forall i \geq n
\end{align}
So :
\begin{equation}
F(X_{n}) = X_{n} \text{ and } X_{i} \subseteq X_{i+1} \; \forall i \in \boldsymbol{N} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}} X_{i} = X_{n}
\end{equation}
We know that $X_{n}$ must be the least fixed point in $\{ X_{i} \}_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}}$. But how do we know that $X_{n}$ is the least fixed
point in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ (i.e. $X_{n} = \overline{X}$) ? If we can prove $\overline{X} \in \{ X_{i} \}_{i \in \boldsymbol{N}}$ then
we are done, but I am not sure how to do this...

So far my solution also hasn't taken into account the fact that $F$ is continuous.

Is this a good way to go about solving this problem ? Can someone help me devise a solution here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. With what you have already shown you can use continuity of $F$ to easily prove that $ Y:=\bigcup X_i$ is in fact a fixed point of $F$ by simply applying $F$, using that $F$ is continuous and that $X_i$ is non-decreasing and the definition of $X_i$.

So now you know by definition of the least fixed point that $\bar X\subseteq Y$.

But then we have:
$$ \emptyset \subseteq \bar X \subseteq Y $$
By using that $F$ is monotonous and that $\bar X,Y$ are fixed points we get
$$ X_1 \subseteq \bar X\subseteq Y$$
and thus recursively for all $i\in\mathbb N$:
$$ X_i\subseteq \bar X \subseteq Y$$
This implies that the union
$$ Y = \bigcup X_i \subseteq \bar X \subseteq Y $$
and this
$$ \bar X = Y $$